# Angular2+ auth guard with firebase realtime database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set a guard to angular routes depending on user's data on firebase realtime database. I've set admin's privilege as dashboard: true on user's realtime database section ([like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLTkC.png)). And I'd like to give a permission to enter some specific routes only if the user has dashboard: true property on his/her database. I tried below code. But it always redirects to the root route (localhost:4200)

```
    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.firebaseAuth.authState.map(auth => {
      if (auth) {
        this.authService.getUserData(auth.uid).subscribe(userData => {
          if (userData['dashboard'] === true) {
            return true;
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
          }
        })
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.firebaseAuth.authState.switchMap(auth => {
        if (auth)
            return this.authService.getUserData(auth.uid).map(userData => {
                if (userData['dashboard'] === true)
                    return true;

                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return false;
            });

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return of(false);
    });
}
```